# How to apply baseline only to a particular component?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

we are using Clearcase UCM. To maintain the configuration items, we created components.

I use to apply baseline for whole project/steram.

Is there any way to apply baseline for particular component alone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also select the component you want when making a baseline (beside the `-component` option of [`cleartool mkbl`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkbl.htm))m if you select an activity including only modified versions in that component.
(you can look at the "Change Set" tab of an activity to look at the extended pathnames of each versions of an activity)

Note that `cleartool mkbl -component` will not create a baseline if there was no modifications since the last baseline.
(unless you force the issue by adding the `-identical` option)

Note also you still need an UCM view (associated to a Stream) to run that command: a baseline (even for just one component) is always created for a given stream (in a given associated view).

I also recommend always making full baselines (`-full` option).
That avoid performance issue when comparing two baselines, since two incremental baselines must go back in the version tree of each file to the last full baseline in order to get back the full list of versions of a given baseline.

---

When used with the `-comp` option, the `mkbl` should put the name of the baseline to create at the **end** (ie last parameter) of the command:

```
cleartool mkbl -comp myComponent@\myPVob aNewBlName
```

Comment: I am trying to execute like the command but facing error . "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC>cleartool mkbl "Datasourceb
uild" -component "Support@\Our_PVOB"
cleartool: Error: Extra arguments: "-component" .Any idea how to solve it? No example i found in net

Comment: @Samselvaprabu I believe the name of the baseline must be the last parameter of your command.

Comment: @Samselvaprabu I have edited the answer to add an example of using that command.

Answer (score 1):

If you use command-lines, you can use `cleartool mkbl -component`

Read the man (`cleartool man mkbl`) for further details.