# ClearCase; How to make a baseline with cleartool

Tags: clearcase, cleartool, baseline

I am currently using ClearCase over a remote network and it is painfully slow. It takes forever just to browse to the stream that I want to make a baseline of. Is there a quick, easy, and safe way to make a baseline from the cleartool interface of a specific stream?

Thanks,

Ian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic command, from [`cleartool man mkbl`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/):

```
 cleartool mkbl -view anUCMView aBaselineName
```

You need a view associated to your target Stream to apply the baseline.
I recommend using the `-full` option, in order to create a full baseline (rather than an incremental one by default).

Using a snapshot or a dynamic view for `mkbl` shouldn't make a difference, but I like working in a snapshot view, and setting my baselines in a dynamic view (in which I am sure I don't have any pending checkouts).

See:

- "[What is the difference between Full baseline and Incremental baseline in Clearcase UCM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696598/what-is-the-difference-between-full-baseline-and-incremental-baseline-in-clearca)".
- "[How to apply baseline only to a particular component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10206785/how-to-apply-baseline-only-to-a-particular-component)" if you need to limit it to one component.

Note: this is for a full ClearCase installation, not CCRC (ClearCase Remote Client).

Comment: With CCRC, the latest changes in 8.0.0.4 still doesn't include any `mkbl` command (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21594728)

Comment: Okay, When I read the documentation I think I read the mkbl command as mklbl. As in I thought it was making a label and not a baseline. Thanks again Von.