# How to find the list of files changed after latest baseline in UCM?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, cleartool

I have to verify whether any elements are changed in a component vob after the last baseline in applied.

I was trying to find the cleartool command for that but i got upto "finding the list of files changed after a particular date " .

Is there any way to get the list of files changed after the last baseline applied?

Answer (score 2):

One of the fastest way would be simply to try and [make a baseline](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13764669/6309)(!)

- If nothing has changed, by default, ClearCase UCM will refuse to make one.
- If one has change:

  - a/ You can compare the newly created baseline with its previous to get the list of versions modified:
    `cleartool diffbl -pred -ver newBaseline@\aPVob`
  - b/ You can delete that newly created baseline if your intention was not to create one right away.

---

Another relatively fast way (since adding/removing a baseline can take time on a large component, or where there are already *a lot of* baselines) is:

"[Find files in Clearcase view newer than a specific date?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7676484/6309)"

If you have the date of the last baseline, you can launch a search for newer version:

```
cleartool find <vobtag>/<component_root_dir> -element "{created_since(target-data-time)}" -print
```

To get the latest baseline, see "[List the latest baseline of a component in a UCM stream one by one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8132683/6309)".
The date can then be obtain with an [`fmt_ccase`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm) directive:

```
 cleartool describe -fmt "%d" aBaselineName@/aPVob
```

Answer (score -1):

The best,simplest and easiest way to do that is by creating a view in that baseline and then give a `cleartool rebase -recommended` .Once you do this just give `cleartool lspriv -co` This will give you list of all the files that have been modified after your baseline in which you created the view.